# How to use finfo to determine multiple file types?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to use finfo to determine if the file is an image file before uploading it into the server. My question though is that the code below is only for jpeg, but I have other file types as well to allow. So I have 2 questions:

Question 1:

How can I use finfo to check for multiple file types such as gif, tiff, png, ico etc.

Question 2: Do I need to use other validation methods to check to see if the is an image or is I what I got below be enough?

Below is code:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimetype = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype('/path/to/file.jpg'));

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/tiff")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/bmp")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/ico")

{

   if ($finfo !== FALSE){

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
    "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

   @finfo_close($finfo);
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? Isn't it already checking for multiple file types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to check whether the file type is an image:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, '/path/to/file.jpg';
finfo_close($finfo);

if (substr ($mimetype, 0, 5) == 'image') {
    // its an image
}
else {
    // its not an image!
}
```

Second option, if you're using PHP 5.2 or lower:

```
$mimetype = mime_content_type('/path/to/file.jpg';

if (substr ($mimetype, 0, 5) == 'image') {
    // its an image
}
else {
    // its not an image!
}
```

As for other validation methods, you should use the `getimagesize()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

```
if (getimagesize ('/path/to/file.jpg')) {
    // its an image
}
else {
    // its not an image!
}
```

This way your script can't be fooled by changing the mime type or extension of a file.

Comment: What I thought is the finfo is just checking for a jpg image, but how does finfo check if its a gif, bmp, tiff, etc? I know `$_FILES["file"]["type"] ` is doing this but I want finfo to do the same thing. Same with the code you provided me, isn't that only checking for jpg only? what about the other image types?

Comment: What's your PHP version? FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE is only available since PHP 5.3.0

Comment: How do you check to see what version of php Im using, I am simply just using crimson editor which is just a text editor to write the code

Comment: Also, I've added code to my post on how to use the finfo_ functions

Comment: I have found out it is version 5.2 . So can't use finfo, thanks for your answer anyway.